# Android - Change background color of Tab onClicked

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have designed an app in that I am using `TabBar` and I want to change the BackgroundColor of `TabBar` when selected or pressed.. In the class where I am implementing `TabBar` is extending `Fragment` not `TabActivity`. I have implemented following

```
tabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(R.id.tabhost); 



    mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(getActivity(), false);

    Intent intentongoing = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(), Properties_org_screen.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecOngoing = tabHost.newTabSpec("On Going").setIndicator("On Going").setContent(intentongoing);


    Intent intentcomplete = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(), Properties_org_screen.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecComplete = tabHost.newTabSpec("Completed").setIndicator("Completed").setContent(intentcomplete);


    Intent intentproposed = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(), Properties_org_screen.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecProposed = tabHost.newTabSpec("Proposed").setIndicator("Proposed").setContent(intentproposed);

    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);


    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecOngoing);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecComplete);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecProposed);



    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
    {
         tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setPadding(2,5,0,10); 
         Log.v("","In for loop");

         TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
         tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);       

    }   
**OnCreate Ends**
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String arg0)
 {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
  {
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_title));     
  }

}
```

I also tried to implement `Custom_tab.xml` as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/new_background"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue"/>


</selector>
```

and calling this file in

```
<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/custom_tab"/>
```

Still not working.. What I am missing??

Comment: That last for loop is useless when you are not using that **i variable**.

Comment: ... and where are you setting the listener to TabHost?

Comment: What if you use this in `onTabChanged(...)` **tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setBackgroundColor(...)**

Comment: `Class Property extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener` what else is remaining???

Comment: `tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);` is missing

Comment: I guess in OnCreate right?? Can u just provide a sample code for the same??

Comment: Yes in there. Add that line under the `tabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);` and it should work!

Comment: and shall I include forloop in method onTabChanged.. or just a single line as tabHost.getCurrentTabView.setBackgroundColor(....)?????

Comment: Its working.. but when I switch to other tabs. previous tab's color is not getting unselected... Its still showing selected.. though I am on other tab..

Comment: @vilpe89 Hey do u have a solution to this?

Comment: Well you can either set some variable to hold the previous tab instance and set its color back to default when new tab is clicked OR loop every tab and set the colors back to default BEFORE setting currently clicked tab.

Comment: Done.. will post the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in `OnCreate`

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
    {
         tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setPadding(2,5,0,10); 
         Log.v("","In for loop");
         TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
         tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

         tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_background);
    }

    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_title));
```

and `TabChanged` method

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
    {           
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_background);
    }

    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_title)); 

}
```

It will display the blue color to tab which is selected and a white image named new_background to the tab which is not selected..

and don't forget to write

```
implements OnTabChangeListener
```

after your class name

and

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
```

after

```
tabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
```

This one is the **Perfect Solution** I guess.